# Set Variable Names from First Row of Matrix

Tags: matlab, variables, matrix

I have a 61x4718 matrix in Matlab composed of the top row of each column being the stockID number with the remaining 60 rows in each column being returns.  Can anyone help with code for setting the  number contained in row 1 of each column to be the variable name while maintaining the returns in the 60 below?

The data looks like this: \

top row  : 10801  12032   13439

rows 2-61: 0.12  0.01   0.04

Thank you!!

Comment: please add language tag...Is this Matlab? Also an example would help.

Comment: Hi, sorry. Yes, it is Matlab.

Comment: just to clarify, you want to combine a string and a number in a matrix? E.g. 1st row: 'header 1' 'header 2' 2nd row: 0.12 0.01

Comment: All I'd like to do is take the number in each column of row 1 and make that the variable name and then have the 60 returns below it in rows 1-60. So I'd have variable 10801 with a column of returns, the first of which would be 0.12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make a variable named `10801` because it is not allowed by matlab. One thing you could do is to make a variable .e.g. 'v10801'. Other posibility is to make [Map](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/containers.mapclass.html) and make keys of the map using the values from the first row. The example of one way of doing this is as follows:

Example **data.txt**:

```
    10801 12032 13439
    0.12 0.41 0.041
    0.52 0.31 0.044
    0.12 0.51 0.05
    0.72 0.61 0.06
    0.12 0.43 0.01
```

Example code reading the data and producing the map:

```
myVarsMap = containers.Map('KeyType', 'int32','ValueType', 'any');

myData = dlmread('data.txt');

firstRow = myData(1,:);

for i = 1:size(myData, 2);
    myVarsMap(firstRow(i)) = myData(2:end, i);
end

myVarsMap.keys
ans = 

    [10801]    [12032]    [13439]


myVarsMap(10801)
ans =

    0.1200
    0.5200
    0.1200
    0.7200
    0.1200
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a variable name that starts with a digit in matlab (as in many other languages). On top of that, you will have to use dirty eval trickery to do exactly what you want. Consider putting your columns as items in a struct (each struct element is one stock):

```
stocks = [];
for p=1:size(your_matrix,2)
    stocks.(['s' num2str(your_matrix(1,p))]) = your_matrix(2:end,p);
end
```

This will give you

```
stocks.s10801 = 60 rows
stocks.s12032 = 60 rows
sotcks.s13439 = 60 rows
```

Answer (score 0):

You SHOULD not use your variable names to represent your data.

Here are two things you can consider:

**If the headers are nicely consisting of numbers**

Create an index, for example:

```
myIdx = `[10801 12032 13439]`
```

Now the place in the index indicates the relevant column. If your index values are nice unique indices you may want to look at the map solution by @Marcin instead.

**If your headers may contain non numeric values**

Consider either writing them in a cell arrray, in that case the place in the cell array still corresponds to the column in the matrix.

```
myIdx = `{10801 'two' 13439}`
```

**If your columns are not of equal length**

You can use a struct, but rather than (ab)using the name of the struct or its fields, just add a name field. Example:

```
S(1).name = 'myfirstheader';
S(1).data = [1:10];
S(2).name = 12345;
S(2).data = rand(1,40)
```